# tikz and beamer: shape rectangle split example from manual

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

The pgf manual has an example using the shape `rectangle split` on page 450 that is not working with the `beamer` class:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Testing}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[my shape/.style={ rectangle split, rectangle split parts=#1, draw, anchor=center}]
    \node [my shape=5] at (0,1) {
      a\nodepart{two}b\nodepart{three}c\nodepart{four}d\nodepart{five}e};
    \node [my shape=5, rectangle split horizontal] at (2,2) {
      1\nodepart{two}2\nodepart{three}3\nodepart{four}4\nodepart{five}5};
    \node [my shape=3] at (3,0.5) {
      A\nodepart{two}B\nodepart{three}C};
    \node [my shape=4, rectangle split horizontal] at (1.5,0.5) {
      1\nodepart{two}2\nodepart{three}3\nodepart{four}4};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

When this document is compiled with pdflatex, it gives the following error message:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \test.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.19   \end{tikzpicture}
```

Is this a known bug?

With the `article` class no error is found in the `tikzpicture` environment.

Comment: I ran into this error message, and for me, the problem was simply a forgotten `\end{frame}`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `#1` seems to cause a problem. However, it can be fixed using the `fragile` option to the frame, which is described in the beamer manual, and causes the frame content to be differently handled.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Testing}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[my shape/.style={ rectangle split,
    rectangle split parts=#1, draw, anchor=center}]
    \node [my shape=5] at (0,1) {
      a\nodepart{two}b\nodepart{three}c\nodepart{four}d\nodepart{five}e};
    \node [my shape=5, rectangle split horizontal] at (2,2) {
      1\nodepart{two}2\nodepart{three}3\nodepart{four}4\nodepart{five}5};
    \node [my shape=3] at (3,0.5) {
      A\nodepart{two}B\nodepart{three}C};
    \node [my shape=4, rectangle split horizontal] at (1.5,0.5) {
      1\nodepart{two}2\nodepart{three}3\nodepart{four}4};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: test frame]

Comment: do you know how to solve this when doing a poster? I am using `\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter} `

Answer (score 1):

You get this error if you try to use a parameter number, e.g., `#1`, inside the definition of a command which doesn't have an argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\test{\def\abc#1{#1}}
\end{document}
```

The solution is to double the parameter in this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\test{\def\abc##1{blub##1}}
\test \abc{cde}
\end{document}
```

In the case of `beamer` (or `beamerposter` package), doubling is not enough, as the content of a frame is stored twice: After doubling you get the same error but now for the command `\beamer@doifinframe` instead of \test.

So the solution is to redouble the parameter sign:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
Node/.style = {rectangle, text width=####1}
]\tiny
\node[Node=5ex] {FFT};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I recommend this solution since in the `beamerposter` package there is not the possibility of using the traditional way of adding `[fragile]` to the frame.

Comment: Normally a `beamerposter` starts with `\begin{document}
\begin{frame}` (for example https://github.com/deselaers/latex-beamerposter/blob/master/examples/01/example.tex)  were `[fragile]` can easily be added.